# “Had complete", “Had completed", “Have complete", Have completed"

Tags: grammar

what's the difference between these sentence ?

- He **had complete** his work.
- He **had completed** his work.
- I **have complete** my work.
- I **have completed** my work.

Does it make sense to use present tense after had ? Like had finish, had go etc

Answer (score 1):

**No**
Generally it doesn't. Of your four examples, only

> He had completed his work.

is grammatically correct. Another possible from would be:

> He has completed his work.

This second form describes the current state of things: the work is now complete, although it was finished in the past. Yet another possible form would be

> His work is complete.

However, this doesn't say whether he completed it or someone else did, a typical issue of using the passive voice.

Answer (score 0):

> ✘ He had complete his work.
>
> ✔ He had completed his work.
>
> ✘ He have complete his work.
>
> ✘ He have completed his work.

In these sentences **"have"** and **"had"** are used as auxiliary verbs.

In **past perfect** tense "Had" is used as auxiliary while "Have" is required in **present perfect** tense. However, in **present perfect** tense if the subject is singular and in third person, "Has" will replace "Have".

> **He Had completed his work**- Past perfect tense

> **He has completed his work**- Present perfect tense, Subject is third person singular, hence "Has" instead of "Have"

These sentences are grammatically correct